# ValueError: "<MODEL MODELOBJECT>" needs to have a value for field "Mrefs" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django

I am getting the following error when trying to add a many to many relationship. The error happens only when I am trying to add the many to many field. The same model with no data to the Many-many field loads fine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/app/PycharmProjects/app/management/commands/import_data_csv.py", line 101, in handle
    ManualRef.manual_reference = Manual.objects.get(mtype=mid)
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1188, in __set__
    manager = self.__get__(instance)
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1178, in __get__
    through=self.field.rel.through,
  File "/home/app/.virtualenvs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 831, in __init__
    (instance, source_field_name))
ValueError: "<MODEL MODELobject>" needs to have a value for field "manual_reference" before this many-to-many relationship can be used
```

my Models:

from django.db import models

```
class ManualRefs(models.Model):
    reference = models.TextField()
    reference_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    manual_reference = models.ManyToManyField('Manual', blank=True, null=True)

class Manual(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey('TDictionary', blank=True, null=True)
    mol = models.ForeignKey('MDictionary', blank=False, null=False)
    mtype = models.ForeignKey('MType', blank=True, null=True)


    def __unicode__(self):

        if self.mtype:
            str = '-'
            seq = (self.mtype.description, self.info.name, self.mol.mol)
            return str.join(seq)
        else:
            return self.pk
```

my code and here is what I am doing :

```
mid = MType.objects.get(description =row[16]) 
ManRef = ManualRefs()
Man = Manual()
for refer in references:
  types, reference = refer.split(':', 1)

  ManRef.reference_type = types
  ManRef.reference = reference
  ManRef.manual_reference = Manual.objects.get(mtype=mid)

  ManRef.save()
  Man.save()
  ManRef.Manual.add(ManRef)
```

What am I doing wrong?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access a `ManyToMany` field, your object must be saved to the database first. That means you can only do `ManRef.manual_reference = Manual.objects.get(mtype=mid)` **after** `ManRef.save()`.